# SQL Server Reporting Services Date/Sum weirdness

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I have 2 columns next to each other in a report I'm building. They contain the same structure, with one small difference. One column looks back in time a little further then the other. I have verified that the data is there to be found. A row group below returns the rows using the same structure. Column A returns the correct data. Column B does not.

Column A Expression

```
=IIF(Format(Fields!IncomingInvoiceDate.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd") > DateAdd("d", -31, Now()), Sum(Fields!Value.Value), 0)
```

Column B Expression

```
=IIF(Format(Fields!IncomingInvoiceDate.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd") >= DateAdd("d", -61, Now()), Sum(Fields!Value.Value), 0)
```

I've tried every single variation I can find, and nothing returns the correct data. I'm on SQL Server 2012. Thanks for any help.

Comment: My suggestion is to change the data set. Use a case statement in the SQL.Am i correct you are trying to do a sumif ?

Comment: If you give us an example of data returned in your dataset, and what your column B Expression is currently returning, and what you want it to return instead, then MAYBE somebody will be able to help you.

Comment: Sorry I can't post the data return for confidentiality reasons, but I can say Column A returns the summed value for records created within 30 days. Column B should return the summed value for records created within 61 days, but instead returns 0.

Comment: I am trying to do a sumif, and have tried a new dataset, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Put your IF inside the SUM instead of the other way around.

Something like this should work. You'll want to change both the 30 day and 60 day expressions to fit this pattern.

Sum(
IIF(Format(Fields!IncomingInvoiceDate.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd") >= DateAdd("d", -61,Now()), Fields!Value.Value, 0)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out nothing has worked, and I redesigned the query completely. Thanks all.